# *-Operator in gas

Tags: linux, gnu-assembler

can anyone explain what the * in the gnu assembler does? Example:

```
jmp *0x804a004
```

This is an entry in a procedure linkage table (plt), maybe someone can clarify what this instruction does and what the * stands for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "*" means that the address to call or jmp is absolute. If you don't specify it, "as" will assume that the operand is relative to the program counter (PC relative addressing).